# Tomcat7.0.40 auto shutdown with a project running on it, its built with Spring MVC, Atmosphere, Apache Shiro, Oracle

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc, tomcat7, shiro, atmosphere

My project is built with SpringMVC, Atmosphere to accomplish real-time push data, this project also integrate with apache shiro to do security control.

This project is running on Apache tomcat7.0.40, Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 16G memory, jvm version is:
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

My problem is: Tomcat always auto shutdown, and this "auto shutdown" seems random.

Can anybody can help me to identify the route cause?

Atmosphere config in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>meteorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/**/*-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.filter.name</param-name>
        <param-value>shiroFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType</param-name>
        <param-value>application/json</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>filterMappingUrlPattern</param-name>
        <param-value>/*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>meteorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My Shiro filter in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I use Spring's scheduled task to push data to client every 6 seconds, related code:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/6 * * * * *")
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        if (isFetchAllData()) {
            List<T> allData = getAll();
            setMainCache(allData);
        } else {
            List<T> updatedData = getUpdated();
            setUpdatedCache(updatedData);
            pushData(updatedData);
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
        throw new ApplicationException(e);
    }
}

private synchronized void pushData(List<T> updatedData) {
    List<TaskUnit> toRemove = new ArrayList<TaskUnit>();
    for (TaskUnit taskUnit : taskUnits) {
        AtmosphereResource resource = taskUnit.getResource();
        Map<String, Object> queryParam = taskUnit.getQueryParam();
        List<T> filteredDataList = filterData(updatedData, queryParam);
        try {
            if (!resource.isResumed() && !resource.isCancelled() && ((AtmosphereResourceImpl)resource).isInScope()) {
                resource.getResponse().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(filteredDataList));
            } else {
                logger.debug("AtmosphereResource isResumed:" + resource.isResumed() + " isCancelled:" + resource.isCancelled() + " isInScope:"+ ((AtmosphereResourceImpl)resource).isInScope());
                toRemove.add(taskUnit);
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            toRemove.add(taskUnit);
            logger.error("Remove task unit from taskunits list", e1);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error("Write List to string failed!", e);
            throw new ApplicationException(e);
        }
    }
    taskUnits.removeAll(toRemove);
}
```

piece of log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001800057b2, pid=3200, tid=7536
#
# JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [tcnative-1.dll+0x57b2]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000007b88000):  JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-1" [_thread_in_native, id=7536, stack(0x000000000c610000,0x000000000c710000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000040

Stack: [0x000000000c610000,0x000000000c710000],  sp=0x000000000c70e280,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [tcnative-1.dll+0x57b2]  Java_org_apache_tomcat_jni_Socket_sendbb+0x72

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.sendbb(JII)I+0
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer()V+22
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/ByteChunk;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)I
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/ByteChunk;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)I
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/ByteChunk;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)I+49
j  org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/ByteChunk;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes([BII)V+38
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer()V+71
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append([BII)V+159
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes([BII)V+15
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write([BII)V+12
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write([BII)V+7
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write([B)V+5
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse.write([BZ)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResponse;+63
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse.write([B)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResponse;+3
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.writeReady(Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResponse;[B)V+2
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.invokeInterceptor(Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResponse;[BII)V+113
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.write(Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResponse;[BII)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AsyncIOWriter;+6
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptorWriter.write(Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResponse;[B)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AsyncIOWriter;+6
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse$2.write([B)V+47
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse.write(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResponse;+70
j  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse.write(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResponse;+3
j  org.iosh.base.service.AbstractWebSocketService.pushData(Ljava/util/List;)V+76
j  org.iosh.base.service.AbstractWebSocketService.run()V+32
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+36
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+7
J  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;
j  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback;)Ljava/lang/Object;+58
j  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInvocation;)Ljava/lang/Object;+40
J  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;
j  org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInvocation;)Ljava/lang/Object;+18
J  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()Ljava/lang/Object;
j  org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+322
j  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.run()V+9
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor140.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+36
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run()V+19
j  org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run()V+4
j  org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run()V+9
j  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun()V+30
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+4
j  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Ljava/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask;)V+1
j  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run()V+15
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+66
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+33
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000b0a6000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7768, stack(0x000000000bfe0000,0x000000000c0e0000)]
  0x000000000b0a6800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=480, stack(0x000000000adb0000,0x000000000aeb0000)]
  0x000000000b0a1000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3612, stack(0x000000000ac90000,0x000000000ad90000)]
  0x0000000008f17800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7316, stack(0x0000000011bd0000,0x0000000011cd0000)]
  0x000000000ab07000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7668, stack(0x000000000c4a0000,0x000000000c5a0000)]
  0x000000000ab08000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5396, stack(0x000000000c0e0000,0x000000000c1e0000)]
  0x0000000008f16800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4344, stack(0x0000000011ad0000,0x0000000011bd0000)]
  0x0000000008f16000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4328, stack(0x00000000119d0000,0x0000000011ad0000)]
  0x0000000008f15000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6668, stack(0x00000000118d0000,0x00000000119d0000)]
  0x0000000008f14800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8108, stack(0x00000000117d0000,0x00000000118d0000)]
  0x0000000008f13800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7648, stack(0x000000000c1e0000,0x000000000c2e0000)]
  0x0000000008f13000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8072, stack(0x0000000009ab0000,0x0000000009bb0000)]
  0x0000000008f12800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-exec-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8044, stack(0x00000000099b0000,0x0000000009ab0000)]
  0x0000000008f11000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7364, stack(0x00000000116d0000,0x00000000117d0000)]
  0x0000000008f10000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7460, stack(0x00000000115d0000,0x00000000116d0000)]
  0x0000000008f0f800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2280, stack(0x00000000114d0000,0x00000000115d0000)]
  0x0000000008f0e800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7068, stack(0x00000000113d0000,0x00000000114d0000)]
  0x0000000008f0e000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8008, stack(0x00000000112d0000,0x00000000113d0000)]
  0x0000000008f0d000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7128, stack(0x00000000111d0000,0x00000000112d0000)]
  0x0000000008f0c800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8124, stack(0x00000000110d0000,0x00000000111d0000)]
  0x0000000008f0c000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3648, stack(0x0000000010fd0000,0x00000000110d0000)]
  0x000000000856c000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7660, stack(0x0000000010ed0000,0x0000000010fd0000)]
  0x000000000856b800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6624, stack(0x0000000010dd0000,0x0000000010ed0000)]
  0x000000000856a800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8056, stack(0x0000000010cd0000,0x0000000010dd0000)]
  0x000000000856a000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8132, stack(0x0000000010bd0000,0x0000000010cd0000)]
  0x0000000008569800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7476, stack(0x0000000010ad0000,0x0000000010bd0000)]
  0x0000000008568800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7976, stack(0x00000000109d0000,0x0000000010ad0000)]
  0x0000000008568000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7392, stack(0x00000000108d0000,0x00000000109d0000)]
  0x0000000008567000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7844, stack(0x00000000107d0000,0x00000000108d0000)]
  0x0000000008566800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6156, stack(0x00000000106d0000,0x00000000107d0000)]
  0x0000000008565800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7028, stack(0x00000000105d0000,0x00000000106d0000)]
  0x0000000008565000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7892, stack(0x00000000104d0000,0x00000000105d0000)]
  0x0000000008fe2000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7840, stack(0x00000000103d0000,0x00000000104d0000)]
  0x0000000008fe1000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Sendfile-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5184, stack(0x00000000102d0000,0x00000000103d0000)]
  0x0000000008fe0800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7528, stack(0x00000000101d0000,0x00000000102d0000)]
  0x0000000008fdf800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6872, stack(0x00000000100d0000,0x00000000101d0000)]
  0x0000000008fdf000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7928, stack(0x000000000ffd0000,0x00000000100d0000)]
  0x0000000008fde000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1672, stack(0x000000000fed0000,0x000000000ffd0000)]
  0x0000000008fdd800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7908, stack(0x000000000fdd0000,0x000000000fed0000)]
  0x0000000008fdc800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6804, stack(0x000000000fcd0000,0x000000000fdd0000)]
  0x0000000008fdc000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=844, stack(0x000000000fbd0000,0x000000000fcd0000)]
  0x0000000008fdb800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7416, stack(0x000000000eaf0000,0x000000000ebf0000)]
  0x0000000008fda800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8168, stack(0x000000000e9f0000,0x000000000eaf0000)]
  0x000000000ab0f000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Poller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3040, stack(0x000000000e8f0000,0x000000000e9f0000)]
  0x000000000ab0e800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Poller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7292, stack(0x000000000e7f0000,0x000000000e8f0000)]
  0x000000000ab0d800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Poller-4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2216, stack(0x000000000e6f0000,0x000000000e7f0000)]
  0x000000000ab0d000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Poller-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7868, stack(0x000000000e5f0000,0x000000000e6f0000)]
  0x000000000ab0c000 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6832, stack(0x000000000e4f0000,0x000000000e5f0000)]
  0x000000000ab0b800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1392, stack(0x000000000d410000,0x000000000d510000)]
  0x000000000ab0a800 JavaThread "http-apr-8081-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5268, stack(0x000000000d310000,0x000000000d410000)]
  0x000000000ab0a000 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7912, stack(0x000000000d210000,0x000000000d310000)]
  0x000000000ab06800 JavaThread "FileWatchdog" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7904, stack(0x000000000c3a0000,0x000000000c4a0000)]
  0x000000000ab05800 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-12" [_thread_blocked, id=7272, stack(0x000000000d110000,0x000000000d210000)]
  0x000000000ab05000 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-11" [_thread_blocked, id=5936, stack(0x000000000d010000,0x000000000d110000)]
  0x000000000ab04000 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-10" [_thread_blocked, id=4620, stack(0x000000000cf10000,0x000000000d010000)]
  0x000000000ab03800 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-9" [_thread_blocked, id=7436, stack(0x000000000ce10000,0x000000000cf10000)]
  0x000000000ab03000 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-8" [_thread_blocked, id=8084, stack(0x000000000cd10000,0x000000000ce10000)]
  0x000000000ab02000 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-7" [_thread_blocked, id=5752, stack(0x000000000cc10000,0x000000000cd10000)]
  0x000000000ab01800 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-6" [_thread_blocked, id=4960, stack(0x000000000cb10000,0x000000000cc10000)]
  0x000000000ab00800 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-5" [_thread_blocked, id=7144, stack(0x000000000ca10000,0x000000000cb10000)]
  0x000000000ab00000 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-4" [_thread_in_native, id=4524, stack(0x000000000c910000,0x000000000ca10000)]
  0x0000000008d13800 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-3" [_thread_blocked, id=7800, stack(0x000000000c810000,0x000000000c910000)]
  0x0000000008ab9800 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-2" [_thread_blocked, id=7532, stack(0x000000000c710000,0x000000000c810000)]
=>0x0000000007b88000 JavaThread "tmTaskScheduler-1" [_thread_in_native, id=7536, stack(0x000000000c610000,0x000000000c710000)]
  0x000000000851b800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7716, stack(0x0000000009bb0000,0x0000000009cb0000)]
  0x0000000007998000 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8088, stack(0x0000000009760000,0x0000000009860000)]
  0x00000000070bd800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7880, stack(0x0000000007650000,0x0000000007750000)]
  0x00000000070b2000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4276, stack(0x0000000007550000,0x0000000007650000)]
  0x00000000070ad000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7212, stack(0x0000000007450000,0x0000000007550000)]
  0x00000000070aa800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7232, stack(0x0000000007350000,0x0000000007450000)]
  0x00000000070a5800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7508, stack(0x0000000007250000,0x0000000007350000)]
  0x0000000000527000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6768, stack(0x0000000006f50000,0x0000000007050000)]
  0x0000000000524800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6252, stack(0x0000000006e50000,0x0000000006f50000)]
  0x000000000055b800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4396, stack(0x00000000024b0000,0x00000000025b0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000051d800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000006d50000,0x0000000006e50000] [id=6956]
  0x00000000070ce800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000007750000,0x0000000007850000] [id=3716]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 71296K, used 40645K [0x00000007aab60000, 0x00000007afa70000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 70336K, 56% used [0x00000007aab60000,0x00000007ad2294b0,0x00000007af010000)
  from space 960K, 96% used [0x00000007af1e0000,0x00000007af2c8000,0x00000007af2d0000)
  to   space 5312K, 0% used [0x00000007af540000,0x00000007af540000,0x00000007afa70000)
 PSOldGen        total 174656K, used 68580K [0x0000000700200000, 0x000000070ac90000, 0x00000007aab60000)
  object space 174656K, 39% used [0x0000000700200000,0x00000007044f9208,0x000000070ac90000)
 PSPermGen       total 71360K, used 71250K [0x00000006fb000000, 0x00000006ff5b0000, 0x0000000700200000)
  object space 71360K, 99% used [0x00000006fb000000,0x00000006ff5949d0,0x00000006ff5b0000)

Code Cache  [0x00000000025b0000, 0x0000000002d10000, 0x00000000055b0000)
 total_blobs=2370 nmethods=1878 adapters=444 free_code_cache=42726464 largest_free_block=8064

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Tomcat81\conf\logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Tomcat81\endorsed -Dcatalina.base=C:\Tomcat81 -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat81 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat81\temp 
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
JRE_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
CLASSPATH=C:\Tomcat81\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Tomcat81\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
PATH=C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Oracle\db11g\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
USERNAME=Administrator
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 44 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 16763996k(11271648k free), swap 33526148k(24216276k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_45-b06), built on Apr  1 2013 12:31:37 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0 (VS2005)

time: Wed Sep 11 15:19:00 2013
elapsed time: 20345 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few observations from your logs : 
1. Many of your daemon threads are in blocked state. 
2. Scheduler threads all blocked except two, this means your two threads are holding some locks or might be in a deadlock, rest all waiting for lock.
3. Your cron job runs every 6 seconds, try to find out the time taken by a thread in private synchronized void pushData(List updatedData). This should be taking more than 6 seconds, thus many threads are waiting for acquiring the lock which is evident from multiple scheduler threads in blocked state at the same time.

Please provide detailed thread stack, so as to identify for what threads are waiting.

Also try to increase your cron frequency depending on time taken to execute one task, then see whther your tomcat kills automatically.